# jQuery .load() losing style

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, stylesheet

I am using jquery to load a partial view.

```
$("#policyMembers").html('<div class=loader></div>').load("<%= Url.Action("PolicyMembers", "Scheme") %>");
```

my partial view looks as follow:

```
<table class="grid">
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>ID Number</th>
    <th>Date Of Birth</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Cover</th>
</tr>
```

for some reason the grid class is not applied when loading the view using jQuery, but when i load it by making use of renderpartial, the style is applied.

any ideas?

Comment: Using .load() doesn't actually assign the "grid" class? Or are you saying that using .load() doesn't apply the correct CSS for the class?

Comment: when using .load the grid class is not applied.

Comment: You closed the <table> tag right?